# Why do I need to put the backticks on the table name `member` in order to select the table?

Tags: mysql

When I did not put the backticks on the table name, it did not select the table.

```
SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE email = ?
```

Comment: Are you running MySQL 8.0.17 or 8.0.18?

Comment: I'm running MySQL 8.0.18

Comment: In those two versions `member` is a reserved word, and has to be enclosed in backticks when used as an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Because in some SQL syntax `member` or `MEMBER` is a reserved keyword. In order to distinguish your table name with `member` you need to use backticks.

```
`member` (instead of) member
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15